# Is there any way to limit number of nodes a user can create in an Organic Groups?

Tags: 7, organic-groups

I'm working on a site where users can submit content in many groups, each of them have to be administered separately. So I've chosen Organic Groups for this purpose. At the same time I have to limit the number of nodes a user can submit in one group.
[Node Limit](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_limit) module would be a pretty straightforward solution but they don't and will not offer per OG limit. Is there any other way to achive this?